# What anime-inspired fighting game had Green Hill Zone as a stage?

Tags: game-identification

In [RadicalSoda's video on Sonic Mania & Sonic Forces](https://youtu.be/Ls-yzDta1eY), at 2:02 he shows a screenshot of an anime-inspired fighting game which included a 3D render of Green Hill Zone as a stage.

From the screenshot I can see the game has a 2v2 fighting system, a blue special gauge, and some sort of basketball hoop.

The only fighting games I can think of with Green Hill Zone would be Sonic the Fighters, Super Smash Bros., or M.U.G.E.N., but the screenshot doesn't resemble any of those titles.

**What fighting game is this which has Green Hill Zone as a playable stage?**

[image: Fighting game with Green Hill Zone]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By googling what fighting game features Kirito (the character on the left, from Sword Art Online), I came across the Wikipedia page for [Dengeki Bunko: Fighting Climax](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dengeki_Bunko:_Fighting_Climax).

Searching that game brought me to multiple pages featuring the same image you posted, such as [this one](https://www.fightersgeneration.com/games/dengeki-bunko-fighting-climax.html), which has the following caption under the image:

> Yes, there's a Sonic The Hedgehog themed stage in this game... but no Sonic. :(

Additionally, on the [Green Hill Zone wiki page](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Hill_Zone#Dengeki_Bunko:_Fighting_Climax), under the list of appearances, this game is listed:

> [image: appearance in game]
>
> In the Japanese arcade game Dengeki Bunko: Fighting Climax, one of the stages taken from the SEGA franchise, aside from Valkyria Chronicles, is Green Hill Zone, with the design taken from Sonic Generations where the Springs and Dashpads are from Modern Sonic and the Rings are also visible.

Comment: This game is also referenced on Sonic's wiki [Green Hill Zone](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Hill_Zone#Dengeki_Bunko:_Fighting_Climax), if you want to add additional info

Comment: Which character spawned the basketball hoop?

Comment: @StevenM.Vascellaro: Tomoka Minato. "A basketball ace at Keishin Academy. Her mother does traditional dance and her father is a tea master, so her manners are naturally impeccable. But when she starts to play basketball...

Tomoka fights with tricky basketball moves along with the other four students from Keishin Academy. Whether shooting into hoops that appear out of nowhere, or changing her opponents into basketballs, she's all about footwork and finesse. There's even a move styled after Japanese traditional dancing."